# Show alert from Chrome Extension "options_ui" page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Chrome Extensions have had a [Version 2](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2) of their options page since Chrome 40. I tried creating an options V2 page with a button that just has a simple `alert`:

js

```
function resetAll() {
  alert("Not yet implemented.");
}

document.getElementById("reset-button").onclick = resetAll;
```

html

```
<button id="reset-button">Reset All</button>
```

When I click the button in the options page, nothing happens. I even pulled up the Javascript Debugger to see if my code was actually being run. And it was, but no alert showed up.

If I use Chrome Extension's [older options page format](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options), the alert shows up without problem.

Is there no way to create a browser-native `alert` with OptionsV2?

Comment: Why would you want to use alert?

Comment: It's a known bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476350

Comment: And it looks like it followed us to 2017. `confirm` has the same problem.

Comment: Still no fix for this. This is not the way things are done :(

Comment: 2020 and this issue is still a thing

Answer (score 7):

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().alert('Are you sure you want to delete X?');
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().confirm('Are you sure you want to delete X?')
```